# Nested Navigation Properties + Generated SQL Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am wondering if the following generated query can somehow be improved.

I have the following linq expression:

```
var gps = DBContext.GPS.Where(x => x.ID == id)
    .Select(c => new
    {
        Id = c.ID,
        Descripcion = c.DESCRIPCION_LARGA,
        Alarmas = c.ALARMAS.Select(a => new
        {
            FechaHora = a.FECHAHORA,
            CercaDescripcion = a.CERCA.DESCRIPCION_LARGA
        })
    });
```

ALARMAS is a navigation property from the GPS entity.  This generates the folowing sql query:

```
SELECT "Project1"."ID"           AS "ID",
    "Project1"."DESCRIPCION_LARGA"  AS "DESCRIPCION_LARGA",
    "Project1"."C1"                 AS "C1",
    "Project1"."GPS_ID"             AS "GPS_ID",
    "Project1"."FECHAHORA"          AS "FECHAHORA",
    "Project1"."DESCRIPCION_LARGA1" AS "DESCRIPCION_LARGA1"
FROM
    (SELECT "Extent1"."ID"         AS "ID",
        "Extent1"."DESCRIPCION_LARGA" AS "DESCRIPCION_LARGA",
        "Join1"."GPS_ID"              AS "GPS_ID",
        "Join1"."FECHAHORA"           AS "FECHAHORA",
        "Join1"."DESCRIPCION_LARGA"   AS "DESCRIPCION_LARGA1",
        CASE
            WHEN ("Join1"."GPS_ID" IS NULL)
            THEN NULL
            ELSE 1
        END AS "C1"
    FROM "GPS" "Extent1"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT "Extent2"."GPS_ID"     AS "GPS_ID",
            "Extent2"."ALARMA_ID"         AS "ALARMA_ID",
            "Extent2"."LOG_ID"            AS "LOG_ID",
            "Extent2"."CERCA_ID"          AS "CERCA_ID",
            "Extent2"."FECHAHORA"         AS "FECHAHORA",
            "Extent3"."ID"                AS "ID",
            "Extent3"."DESCRIPCION_LARGA" AS "DESCRIPCION_LARGA",
            "Extent3"."DESCRIPCION_MED"   AS "DESCRIPCION_MED",
            "Extent3"."DESCRIPCION_CORTA" AS "DESCRIPCION_CORTA",
            "Extent3"."ABREVIACION"       AS "ABREVIACION",
            "Extent3"."CAPA_ID"           AS "CAPA_ID",
            "Extent3"."CATEGORIA_ID"      AS "CATEGORIA_ID",
            "Extent3"."PADRE_ID"          AS "PADRE_ID",
            "Extent3"."REGION_ID"         AS "REGION_ID",
            "Extent3"."FORMA_ID"          AS "FORMA_ID",
            "Extent3"."VERTICE1_LAT"      AS "VERTICE1_LAT",
            "Extent3"."VERTICE1_LNG"      AS "VERTICE1_LNG",
            "Extent3"."VERTICE2_LAT"      AS "VERTICE2_LAT",
            "Extent3"."VERTICE2_LNG"      AS "VERTICE2_LNG",
            "Extent3"."LAT"               AS "LAT",
            "Extent3"."LNG"               AS "LNG",
            "Extent3"."RADIO"             AS "RADIO",
            "Extent3"."ESTADO_ID"         AS "ESTADO_ID",
            "Extent3"."CERCA_ENRUTA_ID"   AS "CERCA_ENRUTA_ID",
            "Extent3"."OBSERVACIONES"     AS "OBSERVACIONES"
        FROM "GPS_ALARMAS" "Extent2"
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "CERCAS" "Extent3"
        ON "Extent2"."CERCA_ID"     = "Extent3"."ID"
        ) "Join1" ON "Extent1"."ID" = "Join1"."GPS_ID"
    WHERE ("Extent1"."ID"        = :p__linq__0)
    ) "Project1"
ORDER BY "Project1"."ID" ASC,
    "Project1"."C1" ASC
```

My question is basically why it is querying for all columns on the table CERCA (Extend3) when only ID and DESCRIPCION_LARGA are needed?

Can this be improved? Or I just should not worry about it?

Thanks in advance and best regards,
Fabian

Comment: The generated SQL does not appear to match your Linq statement, as there are more columns in your SQL statement than there are in your Linq statement.

Comment: Hi Frank, thats the point.  Why is this happening? Please note I am using Oracle (ODP.NET), probably the query provider is not doing the job properly.

Comment: I was implying that this generated SQL statement may not be from the Linq statement you are showing. Did you get this from the SQL Profiler? If so, is it possible your database server is being hit by another query similar to your Linq statement?

Comment: I can assure you the SQL statement is from the Linq statement.  I get the sql statement on the console.  It is a .net core project, oracle + entity framework 6.  The app is configured so it outputs all sql generated statements from linq statement for debugging purposes.

Comment: I would say you should not worry about it. The subquery selects usually doesn't matter - only the final select is important because that's the data which will be fetched on the client.